Is it possible to omit a verb when there’s another verb right behind it?
I found this test question on the internet and apparently the author says the correct answer is ‘knew’ not ‘know’

The movie Jaws, directed by Steven Spielberg, hit the theaters in
1975 and was a huge hit. Millions saw the movie, and even those who
did not know / knew the story.

According to someone who replied to the author’s question, the answer is ‘knew’ since ‘see the movie’ is omitted behind ‘even those who did not’.
‘Know’ seems just fine in that context and it’s way tricky to use ‘knew’ and I don’t think people would prefer writing or saying in such a confusing way. Is it possible to omit a phrase that has a verb in it?

The piece is all about the past. It is written using past tense verbs - hit, was, saw, did not, so you need the past tense (knew') for the final verb. That's why the verb is not 'know', not because of the shortening of 'did not see the movie'.

Why do you find it 'tricky' and 'confusing' to use knew? The sense is not "those who did not know the story", but "even those [people] who did not [see the film] knew the story".

@KateBunting I find it tricky since I believe that 'even those who did not know the story' this one still makes sense. people may ask for further context, but it's not technically wrong, is it?

@MichaelHarvey That's right but that's what I'm missing here. I'm confused because 'even those who did not know the story' this one makes sense to me, as does 'even those who did not knew the story'. they're talking about different things but they both make sense, no?

But that isn't what the author is saying! They claim that millions of people saw Jaws in the 1970s, and even those who didn't see it knew what it was about. To end the sentence with even those who did not know the story doesn't make sense. What about people who didn't know the story?

@KateBunting, I understand that the answer is ‘knew,’ thanks to the people, including you, who left replies to enlighten me. Based on the context, the answer is B. Technically, however, I still wonder if saying ‘even those who did not know the story’ is simply grammatically incorrect, because I don’t believe it is. If there’s even a small chance that it could confuse people, isn’t the test question itself flawed?

Personally, I would punctuate like this, with a comma after 'not': Millions saw the movie, and even those who did not, know / knew the story. To choose 'know' would not make sentence 'ungrammatical', but it would make it awkward and clumsy, because of the sudden departure from an 'in the past framing. and I think that what the question is testing for.

@pheno8 The comma is required after "did not"  to show that (see it) is omitted. The confusion whether to use present tense or past tense is due to the missing comma

As I said, it's not so much grammatically incorrect as meaningless. "Millions saw the movie, and even those who did not know the story..." what about them?

@KateBunting Yes. You are right. I think without the comma  only "know it" is possible.  "did not knew it" sounds awkward.

Two unrelated questions here.
Is the ellipsis licensed? Yes. "Those who did not (see it)" functions as a unit and this unit is the subject of the next verb. It's no different from this situation:

It was infamous among those who saw it and even among those who did not.

Can the present tense be used? Yes, but it's a little less logical. The reasoning that people who didn't see it still know the story today is sound, but combined with the simple past for "didn't see it", it suggests that they only had a limited opportunity to see it and missed it.
If we were talking about a state of knowing that persists into the present, we would be much more likely to combine it with the present perfect for the seeing:

Even those who haven't [seen it] know the story.


Even those who've never [seen it] know the story.

Whereas by linking "didn't see it" and "knew", we relegate both verbs to the past, without commenting on whether anyone still can see the movie and/or know the story today.
Thus, "knew" is better because it doesn't exclude the reality that people can still watch Jaws today.

I think the past - past emhasizes on the fact Jaws were a hit and millions saw it "fresh" and made fuzz around it so intensively that those who didn't see it at the time were introduced to the plot anyway. Now, Jaws are yet another film from 70s and there is no fuzz about it.

@Crowley Yeah, and even in that interpretation, the first past creates the suggestion that there was a window of opportunity / time when they might have seen it, but didn't. They didn't "catch the first wave" or something. If it's past - present, then it seems like that window is somehow permanently closed, which is probably not the intended meaning.

I would read it as past-past means the frame of relevance is gone in the past - no one cares how many people know the plot nowadays. In case of past-present I would read it as the folm was so significant that even after 45 years people (not even concieved at the time of the premiere) know the plot from the omnipresent discussion of it.

@Crowley Yes, but in addition, the second reading carries the idea that the chance to see it is gone. Again, this is certainly not impossible, just less likely to be what's intended (in my mind). The whole frame is the past. But the snippet is so short that one more sentence before or after could blow either theory out of the water.
